# Excel vba: error hiding calculated field in Pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have written several Subs to show/hide fields in a PivotTable.
Now I am trying to do the same with a calculated field, but I get an error when hiding it.
I took my code from the recorder and the recorder's code also halts on the last line.
I googled the error message, without serious result.

```
Sub PrRemove()
    'remove PR
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivot")
    pt.PivotFields("MyField").Orientation = xlHidden   '<- here is the error
End Sub
```

The same code works fine if MyField is a normal field (not a calculated one).
I am using Excel 2007 with SP2.
Any clue ?

**EDIT on 17 June 2010**: I also tried using pt.DataFields instead of pt.PivotFields, with exactly the same behaviour.  The error message says "Unable to set the orientation of the PivotField class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I will give you the confirmation you need. It seems using the `Orientation` property on a "Calulated Field" just does not work, and I would have to agree this is a bug and not a common "usage" error. I was able to duplicate "hiding/showing" the field without having to remove ("Delete") the calculated field. This allows the user to physically drag the calculated field from the field list after you have progammatically "hidden" the field. This is not a bad solution because it duplicates the user-interface. (Using Excel 2003.)

```
'2009.09.25 AMJ
'work around for
'   1004, Unable to set the Orientation property of the PivotField class
'when setting orientation property to hidden of calculated field, as in
'   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Field1").Orientation = xlHidden

Public Sub Hide()
'hide the data without removing the calculated field
'   this allows the user to physically drag the
'       calculated field from the field list once we
'       have "hidden" it programmatically.
'   if we use the "delete" method, the field is removed
'       from the pivot table and the field list

    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim oPT As PivotTable
    Dim oPF As PivotField
    Dim oPI As PivotItem

    Set oWS = ActiveSheet
    Set oPT = oWS.PivotTables(1)

    For Each oPF In oPT.DataFields
        If oPF.SourceName = "Field1" Then
            'Stop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Set oPI = oPF.DataRange.Cells(1, 1).PivotItem
    'oPI.DataRange.Select
    oPI.Visible = False

End Sub

Public Sub Show()
'show just reads the pivot field to the data fields

    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim oPT As PivotTable
    Dim oPF As PivotField

    Set oWS = ActiveSheet
    Set oPT = oWS.PivotTables(1)

    For Each oPF In oPT.PivotFields
        If oPF.SourceName = "Field1" Then
            'Stop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    oPT.AddDataField oPF

End Sub
```

---

[original answer]
<strike>Most likely you cannot hide this item because it is the last visible item. Instead, try removing it.</strike>

Comment: It is not the last visible. I can do that by hand, record it. It just does not replay.
All I found was this thread, suggesting this is a known bug:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/60fa78ed-0913-4bf5-9c47-2bc0eea59a2c

Comment: Delete works, but that deletes the calculated field, which I can't re-add then.

Comment: I don't understand why you can re-add it?

Comment: AMissico: yes, you're right, I could re-add it. But I am looking first for a "clean" solution, before going to the workaround.
I really think this is an Excel bug, infact, but I'd like to have come confirmation OR learn something :-)

Comment: If you believe it is bug, call Microsoft and there will be no charge. They might even have a fix or proven work around. It does look like a bug considering the link you provided.

Comment: @AMissico: good idea, I didn't think about that, I lost faith in M$ support long time ago, but I'll give them a try.

Comment: I gave you the point since I don't see other solution except waiting a year or 2 for m$ to react.

Comment: Well, I will give you some confirmation. I was not able to find a "clean" solution. It seems using the Orientation property on a Calulated Field just does not work, and I would have to agree this is a bug and not a "usage" error. I was able to duplicate "hiding" the field without having to remove ("Delete") the calculated field, and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

after much hair pulling i have found a workaround.
if you add more than one pivot field (calculated or otherwise) excel creates a grouped field called Values. you can set the orientation property of PivotField("Values") to xlHidden and it bullets both fields. So if you want to remove a calculated field, just add a non-calculated field, set PivotField("Values").orientation to xlHidden and you're done.

nobody said it would be pretty...

Comment: Thanks ! I'll give it a try in a few days. It's never too late :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivottableName").PivotFields("Values")
    .PivotItems("CalcFieldName").Visible = False
End With
```

Comment: Please do not post a code-only answer. Provide an explanation on how it works or why it is a solution. Otherwise, it's more suitable to be a comment once you have the reputation required. http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: looks interesting. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i neded. i have a code to switch pivot datafield values from item to calculated item and back, the code of ".Orientation = xlHidden " worked fine on items but gave the error message on calculated items. now its working perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to easily remove data fields (calculated fields or not), like it would be done manually.

And I finally found this solution (Excel 2010) :

```
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("mypivottable")
For Each pi In pt.DataPivotField.PivotItems
    pi.Visible = False
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little workaround I discovered today, again not very elegant but at least it doesn't need much code, it will hide ALL the fields and you will need to reshow the ones you want after:

```
objTable.DataPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden
```

You may run into an error if excel for some reason thinks the datapivotfield is empty, but to fix this just add in another field as a datafield right before the above statement. Also make sure its the letter l not the number 1 in xlHidden vba's default font has them looking very very similar.

Happy Coding

Comment: Can you please explain how to use your line of code? Definitely it looks like taken from larger whole of code.

Comment: Yes, this simple code line is good for hiding all previously used `Datafields`, but it only works, if you already have at least 2(!) datafields. If you only have one or none, then you'll get an error. So in fact, a loop over all datafields is better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that to hide a calculated field you need to first hide a pivot field called "Values".

```
PivotTable(1).PivotFields("Values").Orientation = xlHidden
For Each PF In PT.DataFields
    PF.Orientation = xlHidden
Next PF
```

I'm assuming that field only seem to exist if you've got two or more fields in your xlDataField position.

Thanks Alinboss for pointing me in the right direction. I was sure I tried your method before and failed - turns out the order is important!

P.s. Your code still does not work with only one calculated data field

Answer (score 1):

Laurent Bosc's code checks out so I voted it up.  My full code includes adding data after hiding it all.  The code is placed on Sheet1(Sheet1).

```
Private Sub Refresh_Pivot()

    Dim NewMetric As String
    Dim pt As PivotTable, objDataField As Object
    NewMetric = "your_custom_metric"

'-------update pivot table 1, hide all elements including calculated field----

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set pt = Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    For Each Pi In pt.DataPivotField.PivotItems
        Pi.Visible = False
    Next

'--------add a new data field to the pivot table----------------------------

    With pt
        .AddDataField.PivotFields(NewMetric), "Sum of " & NewMetric, xlSum
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the name of the calculated field?  Was it originally 'Sum of MyField'?  Try looking at the SourceName property and if it's different using that.

Have you tried `pt.CalculatedFields("MyField").Orientation = xlHidden` ?

Comment: I have tried with both. I had already done this with other fields with no problem. It only bugs with the calculated field. ANd the strange think is that recorded macro does not replay !!

Comment: By any chance, when recording the macro, did you select exactly the cells to be in the pivot table, or did you select the entire sheet or entire columns?  I have noticed that when you select the range in this way the macro records incorrectly.

Comment: @DaveParillo: I recorded ok. I had already coded for 2 "real" fields" successfully, and I copy/pasted the same code. The problem just happens with the calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an excel bug, I think it's a 'feature'.  ;-)

Re: @AMissico, there is no problem in excel hiding all of the fields in a pivot table, but he may be talking about items - you can't hide the last item in a pivot field.

This is the code I routinely use to do what you are trying to do.  These macros were developed on Excel 2002 & 2003. I don't hide CalculatedFields, I delete them.

```
' Hide all fields.
' @param ThePivotTable to operate upon.
Sub HidePivotFields(ByVal ThePivotTable As PivotTable)
    Dim pField As PivotField
    For Each pField In ThePivotTable.CalculatedFields
        pField.Delete
    Next pField
    For Each pField In ThePivotTable.PivotFields
        pField.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next pField

    Set pField = Nothing
End Sub

' Removes FieldName data from ThePivotTable
Sub HideField(ByVal ThePivotTable As PivotTable, _
              ByVal FieldName As String)
    If FieldExists(ThePivotTable, FieldName) = True And _
       CalculatedFieldExists(ThePivotTable, FieldName) = False Then
        ThePivotTable.PivotFields(FieldName).Orientation = xlHidden
    End If
End Sub

' Returns True if FieldName exists in ThePivotTable
'
' @param ThePivotTable to operate upon.
' @param FieldName the name of the specific pivot field.
Function FieldExists(ByVal ThePivotTable As PivotTable, _
                     ByVal FieldName As String) As Boolean
    Dim pField As PivotField

    For Each pField In ThePivotTable.PivotFields
        If pField.SourceName = FieldName Then
            FieldExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pField

    Set pField = Nothing
End Function

' Checks if the field FieldName is currently a member of the
' CalculatedFields Collection in ThePivotTable.
' @return True if a CalculatedField has a SourceName matching the FieldName
' @return False otherwise
Function CalculatedFieldExists(ByVal ThePivotTable As PivotTable, _
                               ByVal FieldName As String) As Boolean
    Dim pField As PivotField

    CalculatedFieldExists = False

    For Each pField In ThePivotTable.CalculatedFields
        If pField.SourceName = FieldName Then
            CalculatedFieldExists = True
        End If
    Next pField
    Set pField = Nothing
End Function

' Returns a Pivot Field reference by searching through the source names.
'
' This function is a guard against the user having changed a field name on me.
' @param ThePivotTable to operate upon.
' @param FieldName the name of the specific pivot field.
Function GetField(ByVal ThePivotTable As PivotTable, _
                  ByVal FieldName As String) As PivotField
    Dim pField As PivotField

    For Each pField In ThePivotTable.PivotFields
        If pField.Name <> "Data" Then
            If pField.SourceName = FieldName Then
                Set GetField = pField
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next pField

    Set pField = Nothing
End Function

' Counts the number of currently visible pivot items in a field.
' @param ThePivotItems the collection of pivot itemns in a field.
' @return the count of the visible items.
Function PivotItemCount(ByVal ThePivotItems As PivotItems) As Long
    Dim pItem As PivotItem
    Dim c As Long

    For Each pItem In ThePivotItems
        If pItem.Visible = True Then c = c + 1
    Next pItem
    PivotItemCount = c
    Set pItem = Nothing
End Function

' Hides a single pivot item in a pivot field, unless it's the last one.
' @param FieldName pivot field containing the pivot item.
' @param ItemName pivot item to hide.
Sub HidePivotItem(ByVal ThePivotTable As PivotTable, _
                  ByVal FieldName As String, _
                  ByVal ItemName As String)
    Dim pField As PivotField

    Set pField = GetField(ThePivotTable, FieldName)
    If Not pField Is Nothing Then
        If PivotItemCount(pField.PivotItems) > 1 Then
            pField.PivotItems(ItemName).Visible = False
        End If
    End If

    Set pField = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: "you can't hide the last item in a pivot field." Isn't that what I said?

Comment: Yes, but the question was about a PivotField, not a PivotItem.  So I thought your reference to 'this item' was referring to @Patrick Honorez's code, so I was just trying to clarify.

Comment: @DaveParillo, Got it. It would have been clearer if I said, "you cannot hide this pivot field because it must have at least one visible item. For reference, in code, this condition generates an error. In Excel's user-interface, the user is prompted with "At least one item must be selected for display in this field." if they unselect all items for a field.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem as you.
It looks like I'm going to have to delete the calculated field and readd it rather than hiding/showing it.

Comment: Good to know. It seems to be the only solution to that Excel "inconsistency".

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally discovered a workaround to this the first time I attempted to hide a calculated field, so thought I would share it here:

Instead of modifying the orientation property, you can instead instruct the code to select the cell in the pivot table that contains the title of the calculated field you want to hide, and then delete the selection.  This works as long as you have another datafield already in the table.  Example below:

Scenario: Pivot table covers the range A1:G10.  Calculated field "Margin" is already in the table, and you want to add the data field "Sales" and remove the "Margin" calc field.

Code to execute:

```
'Add Sales data field
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pname).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    Pname).PivotFields("SALES"), "Sum of SALES", xlSum

 'At this point, the datafield titles are in vertically adjacent rows, named "Sum
 'of Margin" and "Sum of Sales" at locations B3 and B4 respectively.

 'Remove the "Sum of Margin" calculated field
  Range("B3").Delete
```

Not sure why this works, but I'm glad we at least have this to work with!

Comment: Jeremy B: this is not really a calculated field. If you already have Units field and Cost field, then having an Amount field = Units * Costs, that is a calculated field. But thanks anyway for the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there is a very easy way to hide a datafield. You were all wrong mistakeing pivotfields with datafields. I'm presenting a piece of code that empties a pivot table no matter how many pivot fields/data fields were initially in the pivot :

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim p As PivotTable
Dim f As PivotField

Set p = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

For Each f In p.PivotFields

If f.Orientation <> xlHidden Then
    f.Orientation = xlHidden
End If

Next f

For Each f In p.DataFields

If f.Orientation <> xlHidden Then
    f.Orientation = xlHidden
End If

Next f

End Sub
```

Comment: that looks really interesting! I'll check out and come back to you. Thanks for the info.

Comment: your remark about datafields was right, but unfortunately that does not solve the problem on *calculated* fields (see question edits)

Comment: Hy, i don't understand, datafields are calculated fields, i applied this code on a huge variety of pivot tables and it clears all the datafields/pivotfields/calculatedfields.
Pay attention it doesn't delete the pivot table only clears it.

Did you tried my code and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is kind of late, but i see that this problem has not been answered confidently yet and i was facing the same problem having hard time to find useful info. So, i hope this post may help somebody...

If you have your data stored in data model, then instead of PivotFields, use CubeFields .
I had the same problem and i experimented with a simple workbook which did not had a data model and my code worked perfectly (using PivotFields).
It only returned error in the workbook with the data model.
So, i made this change and boom! it worked!
My suggestion is to use the following code:

```
Sub PrRemove()
'remove PR
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivot")
pt.CubeFields("MyField").Orientation = xlHidden   '<- here is the error
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user4709164 answer i got this code, its working perfectly for me:

my pivot columns all ends with X or Y to indicate axis so i use the last char for field caption.

```
Public Sub PivotFieldsChange()
Dim ValType As String, param As String
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pt As PivotTable

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet = "mysheet"
'select between % calculated column or normal column
If Range("Z1").Value = 1 Then
    ValType = "%"
Else: ValType = ""
End If
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each pt In Sheets(Sheet).PivotTables
    Select Case pt.Name
        Case "case1": param = "param1"
        Case "case2": param = "param2"
        Case "case3": param = "param3"
        Case Else: GoTo line1
End Select
pt.PivotFields("Values").PivotItems("X").Visible = False
pt.PivotFields("Values").PivotItems("Y").Visible = False

pt.PivotFields (param & ValType & "_X")
pt.PivotFields(param & ValType & "_X").Orientation = xlDataField
pt.PivotFields (param & ValType & "_Y")
pt.PivotFields(param & ValType & "_Y").Orientation = xlDataField
For Each pf In pt.DataFields
    pf.Function = xlAverage
    pf.Caption = Right(pf.Caption, 1)

Next
line1:
Next pt
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```