# VBA - works in debug but sometimes get runtime error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table and I am "dummy proofing" it for co-workers. I've created 7 buttons, one for each day of the week. I've attached macro's to them so that the pivot table changes the layout to display data for the day when the button is clicked. It works sometimes, but I often get "Run-Time error '1004':  Unable to set the Orientation property of the PivotField class" error. I select debug and run it in VBA and it works fine. I close VBA and then the macro works... sometimes. Then repeats the process all over.

This is code for one of the days (They are all the same except when setting the visible field, I use the specific day):

```
   Sub Sun()
'Sunday Macro

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2 Mon").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("3 Tue").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("4 Wed").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("5 Thu").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("6 Fri").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("7 Sat").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 8
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_2_Mon").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_3_Tue").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_4_Wed").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_5_Thu").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_6_Fri").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_7_Sat").ClearManualFilter
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun")
        .SlicerItems("6am").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("x").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("off").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("5th").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("6th").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("PTO").Selected = True
    End With
End Sub
```

When I open the debug, the first activesheet command is highlighted hinting that I should start my fixing here.

The button to run the macro is on the sheet that it needs to run on, so there is no reason to specify the sheet but I've tried it both ways and still same problem.

Thoughts?

Updated code still gets same error.

Here is the updated version with sheet specified:

```
    Sub Tue()
'Tuesday Macro

Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2 Mon").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("3 Tue").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("4 Wed").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("5 Thu").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("6 Fri").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("7 Sat").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    With Sheets("CrewSheets").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("3 Tue")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 8
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_2_Mon").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_3_Tue").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_4_Wed").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_5_Thu").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_6_Fri").ClearManualFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_7_Sat").ClearManualFilter
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_3_Tue")
        .SlicerItems("off").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("x").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("5th").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("6th").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("PTO").Selected = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: specify the sheet: `Worksheet("Sheet1")` instead of using `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Through some testing, I've learned that when I first open the workbook, the first time I click on a day, the code works but does not on a second click of a different day (which day does not seem to be relevant). If I am already selected on any other day aside from sunday, when I click sunday, it will allow me to click Monday on my second try. Only seems to work with sunday selected first then Monday. No other day combination seemed to allow me to select other days beyond the first try.

Comment: I've tried it with the sheet specified before but did as you suggested. Performed multiple tests again, same error.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "Run-Time error '1004': Unable to set the Orientation property of the PivotField class"

Comment: Maybe try looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388244/excel-vba-error-hiding-calculated-field-in-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unadvised to use `ActiveSheet` in a macro, especially if the worksheets of your workbook look differently (which is most probably the case here).

If your code is relevant for different sheets, then you might start your macro with something like:

```
if ActiveSheet.Name <> "This is the correct one"
then Exit sub
else ... (here you have the rest of your original macro)
end if
```

Good luck

As the problem seems not to be related to the sheet itself, I've been looking for another solution and I found [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388244/excel-vba-error-hiding-calculated-field-in-pivot-table).

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I've ran it with active sheet and specified sheet and both give me the same error. As suggested though, I've specified the sheet to avoid any future possible errors.

Comment: @Jason: I've been looking on the site and found a question with a similar error message. Can you check this out?

Comment: I tried to read through that discussion and I think that there was a solution but I'm not sure how to get it to work with my code. I tried a more recent solution that was posted (the one with pivotitems.visible=false but no feedback if it was an actual solution) but I couldn't get that one to work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat same code over and over. Instead use procedures and functions with parameters like shown below.

The `Sub Sun()`, `Sub Mon()` and so on are only needed if you want to link them to a button or something. Otherwise you can omit them and directly run `PreparePivot "1 Sun"` form other procedures if needed.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Sun()
    PreparePivot "1 Sun"
End Sub

Public Sub Mon()
    PreparePivot "2 Mon"
End Sub

'and so on for other days

Private Sub PreparePivot(ByVal DayName As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetThatHasYourPivot") 'adjust
    
    With ws
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("1 Sun").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("2 Mon").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("3 Tue").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("4 Wed").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("5 Thu").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("6 Fri").Orientation = xlHidden
        .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("7 Sat").Orientation = xlHidden
        
        With .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(DayName) 'here it uses the parameter DayName that was submitted
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 8
        End With
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_1_Sun").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_2_Mon").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_3_Tue").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_4_Wed").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_5_Thu").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_6_Fri").ClearManualFilter
        .SlicerCaches("Slicer_7_Sat").ClearManualFilter
        
        With .SlicerCaches("Slicer_" & Replace$(DayName, " ", "_")) 'here it replaces the space in the parameter eg "1 Sun" with an underscore "1_Sun"
            .SlicerItems("6am").Selected = True
            .SlicerItems("x").Selected = True
            .SlicerItems("off").Selected = False
            .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = False
            .SlicerItems("5th").Selected = True
            .SlicerItems("6th").Selected = True
            .SlicerItems("PTO").Selected = True
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This way the long code is only written once and you just need the short subs to link them to a button. This way the code is much easier to maintain and easier to make consistant for all days.

Comment: So far, my experience with VBA is making changes to recorded macros which is limited. I tried your method and it works great! ….  except that I still get the same error.   Run-Time error '1004': Unable to set the Orientation property of the PivotField class. I also need to point out that it generally only happens on the second time I click a day (except Sunday to Monday). After I've clicked a day, if I want to change days again, I have to close it out, reopen, and then I can click a different day.

Comment: Not sure if VBA can do this, but I was thinking that if VBA can check to see what field is located in position 8 (for example), then insert that field into the x1Hidden command, it would reduce the likelihood of an error. I think the error is happening because I am asking the code to hide fields that are already hidden... maybe?